# summing binomial coefficiens related

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k}$ how to prove $s_{n+1}+2s_n+s_{n-1}=0$. One of my student had this question in his exam. Honestly to speak I couldn't get any single idea how to even start. I knew some strategies to find binomial sums but they all couldn't help. It would be great if someone helps.

Comment: Please provide additional [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Can you calculate $s_1, s_2, s_3$? FWIW I do not get $s_3 - 2 s_2 + s_1 = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Let us prove a stronger result: for $n\ge1$
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k}=(-1)^n(2n+1),\quad\tag1
c_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}=(-1)^n 4n.
$$

Indeed for $n=1$ the formula $(1)$ is valid as can be easily checked. Assume it is valid for some $n\ge1$. Then it is valid for $n+1$ as well:
$$
\begin{align}
c_{n+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\left[\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}+\binom{n+k-1}{2k-2}\right]\\
&=c_n-4s_n\\&
=(-1)^n4n-(-1)^{n}4(2n+1)\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}4(n+1);\\
\vphantom{X}\\
s_{n+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+1+k}{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\left[\binom{n+k}{2k}+\binom{n+k}{2k-1}\right]\\
&=s_n+c_{n+1}\\&
=(-1)^n(2n+1)+(-1)^{n+1}4(n+1)\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}(2(n+1)+1).
\end{align}$$

Thus by induction the formula $(1)$ is proved. The original statement is a trivial corollary.

Comment: Thanku so much. Yes there is a correction in  question statement. Really a nice proof. Even to prove by induction it's hard to guess the formula first.

Comment: @YBR I have just computed a couple of first terms to see the simple pattern.

Comment: thank you. That will be doable and good.

Comment: In fact if one *assumes* that $s_{n+1}+2s_n+s_{n-1}=0$ is correct it immediately follows that $s_n=(-1)^n(a n+b)$ and it remains only to find $a$ and $b$. For this task two first values suffice.

Answer (score 3):

This answer proves that $s_{n+1}+2s_n+s_{n-1}=0$ without proving that $s_n=(-1)^n(2n+1)$. (**user**'s answer is helpful.)

First, we have
$$\begin{align}s_{n+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+1+k}{2k}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\bigg(\binom{n+k}{2k}+\binom{n+k}{2k-1}\bigg)
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\color{red}{n+1}}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k-1}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\color{red}n}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k-1}
\\\\&=s_n+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k-1}\end{align}$$

So, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k-1}=s_{n+1}-s_n\tag1$$

Also, we have
$$\begin{align}&\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k-1}\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\bigg(\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}+\binom{n+k-1}{2k-2}\bigg)
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\color{red}{n+1}}(-4)^k\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=\color{blue}0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+k-1}{2k-2}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\color{red}n}(-4)^k\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=\color{blue}1}^{n+1}(-4)^{k}\binom{n+k-1}{2k-2}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}-4\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-4)^{k-1}\binom{n+k-1}{2k-2}
\\\\&\operatorname*{=}_{\color{red}{j=k-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}-4\sum_{j=0}^{n}(-4)^{j}\binom{n+j}{2j}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^{k}\binom{n-1+k}{2k-1}-4s_n\end{align}$$

So, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-4)^k\binom{n+k}{2k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^{k}\binom{n-1+k}{2k-1}-4s_n\tag2$$

Therefore, it follows from $(1)(2)$ that
$$s_{n+1}-s_n=(s_{n}-s_{n-1})-4s_n$$
from which we finally get
$$s_{n+1}+2s_n+s_{n-1}=0$$

Comment: Thanks Mathlove for Nice Explanation. Can u please explain me How we get $\displaystyle s_{n}=(-1)^n(2n+1)$ without using Induction.

Comment: @DXT : We already have $s_{n+1}+2s_n+s_{n-1}=0$ which can be written as $s_{n+1}+s_n=-(s_n+s_{n-1})$, so we get $s_{n+1}+s_n=(-1)^{n-1}(s_2+s_1)=2(-1)^{n-1}$. Dividing the both sides by $(-1)^{n+1}$ gives $t_{n+1}-t_n=2$ where $t_n=\frac{s_n}{(-1)^n}$. So, we get $t_n-t_1=2(n-1)$ which implies that $s_n=(-1)^nt_n=(-1)^n(2n+1)$.